# Choose lowest value in each row R

Tags: r, dataframe, minimum

I have the df below.

```
     Postcode    A      B      C        D      E

 1     4251     45.8   55.1   70.2     79.5    102  
 2     4254     41.7   51.0   66.1     75.3    97.9  
 3     4255     45.5   48.7   63.9     73.1    95.6  
 4     4681     114    100    96.4     102     125
```

I want the minimum value of each row where postcode is not a number but a character.

expected output:

```
  Postcode   Dis  Location
1  4251      45.8   A
2  4254      41.7   A
3  4255      45.5   A
4  4681      96.4   C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = A:E, names_to = "Location", values_to = "Dis") |>
  group_by(Postcode) |>
  filter(Dis == min(Dis))
  

+ # A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   Postcode [4]
  Postcode Location   Dis
  <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
1 4251     A         45.8
2 4254     A         41.7
3 4255     A         45.5
4 4681     C         96.4
```

Comment: > is unexpected token. I installed the tidyr packages

Comment: The `|>` syntax needs at least R-4.1. You can use `%>%` instead, with the same effect.

Comment: ah TY.  %>% from dyplr. That is better for me to understand